# Block outgoing call from WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, call, voip, whatsapp

I want to block outgoing VOIP call from WhatsApp. I can detect if there is a call using AudioManager, but don't know how to reject/stop it. I can't find something like `stop()` or `cancel()` in AudioManager instance.

Comment: What did you tried already?

Comment: I've searched on the internet but can't find anything useful, just some people have same concern as me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491633/detect-incoming-voip-calls-in-android.html